# How to avoid testing implementation details when testing that an action creator is called?

Tags: redux, react-testing-library

I'm new to testing, and I'm writing tests for a large React app that uses Redux, and I'm trying to follow the "Avoid testing implementation details" philosophy of React Testing Library.

But I'm not sure how to proceed when testing that action creators are called correctly. I plan to test the action creators separately, so no need to ensure that they dispatch actions in this context.

Suppose I have a list of items to manage. If I delete or create one, as a user, I would expect to see a change in the list. I could easily test that the action creator is called by rendering the component unconnected and passing a jest spy as the action creator, but that would be testing implementation details(and has other drawbacks, in my case). If I wanted to test this in a way that emulates the behavior a user would expect, I would need for the action creator to actually dispatch its action to the reducer and alter the store. And that would require a separate testing API, which comes with its own issues. Refactoring action creators to check if they are being called by a test in order to skip the regular API call is not a good option.

What is the best way to proceed here? I suspect I'm overthinking it a bit and there is a simple solution but I've been unable to find or come up with anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. First I would follow [this example](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-redux) to set up my test. I would render the component that shows the list and that is connected to the store.

At this point, I would use `fireEvent` to simulate a user that interacts with your app. You could simulate a click on the button that deletes an item for example. Once I've simulated the click, the action will be dispatched, the store will be updated and the app re-rendered. I would then check that the list is correctly updated.

```
/*
In this test I'm assuming the output of List is something like this:
<ol>
  <li>Foo <button>Delete Foo</button></li>
  <li>Bar <button>Delete Bar</button></li>
  <li>Baz <button>Delete Baz</button></li>
</ol>
*/
test('It's possible to remove elements from the list', () => {
  const { getByText, queryByText } = renderWithRedux(<List />)
  expect(getByText('Foo')).toBeInTheDocument()
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Delete Foo'))
  expect(queryByText('Foo')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```